# Apache Spark Scala : How to maintain order of values while grouping rdd by key

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

May be i am asking very basic question apology for that, but i didn't find it's answer on internet. I have paired RDD want to use something like aggragateByKey and concatenating all the values by a key. Value which occur first in input RDD should come first in the aggragated RDD.

```
Input RDD [Int, Int]
 2 20
 1 10
 2 8
 2 25

Output RDD (Aggregated RDD)
2 20 8 25
1 10
```

I tried aggregateByKey and gropByKey, both are giving me ouput, but order of values is not maintained. So please suggest something in this.

Comment: You can try to reorder each collection after being aggregated. Have you tried that ?

Comment: How can i reorder it, i do not need id desc or asc. i need ordering based on input rdd.

Comment: When you groupByKey, you'll get a RDD[(Int, Iterable[Int])] , right ? Than you can use a transformation to map over your RDD values, convert them into an Array and sort that array.

Comment: I believe that you want to order values and not keys, right ?

Comment: Thanks for reply, please check output RDD which i have mentioned in my question. Output values are not ordered by greater or lesser than, but they are ordered by the sequence of arrival in Input RDD.

Comment: yes order by values

Comment: Then my comment here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39287480/apache-spark-scala-how-to-maintain-order-of-values-while-grouping-rdd-by-key#comment65909228_39287480 should help you

Comment: I want sort by value, but sorting should not be based on ascii values it should be based on input RDD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `groupByKey` and `aggregateByKey` indeed cannot preserve order - you'll have to artificially add a "hint" to each record so that you can order by that hint yourself after the grouping:

```
val input = sc.parallelize(Seq((2, 20), (1, 10), (2, 8), (2, 25)))

val withIndex: RDD[(Int, (Long, Int))] = input
  .zipWithIndex()  // adds index to each record, will be used to order result
  .map { case ((k, v), i) => (k, (i, v)) } // restructure into (key, (index, value))

val result: RDD[(Int, List[Int])] = withIndex
  .groupByKey()
  .map { case (k, it) => (k, it.toList.sortBy(_._1).map(_._2)) } // order values and remove index
```